# How to get just the relational fields of a model?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my model, the question is below.

```py
from django.db import models

# ...

class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("Numele județului"))
    capital = models.ForeignKey("Municipality", on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name="capital_of", verbose_name=_("Reședința"))
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region, related_name="counties", verbose_name=_("Regiunea"))
    area = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Suprafața"))
    population = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Populația"))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Descrierea"))
    north = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_south", verbose_name=_("Nord"))
    northeast = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_southwest", verbose_name=_("Nord-est"))
    east = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_west", verbose_name=_("Est"))
    southeast = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_northwest", verbose_name=_("Sud-est"))
    south = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_north", verbose_name=_("Sud"))
    southwest = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_northeast", verbose_name=_("Sud-vest"))
    west = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_east", verbose_name=_("Vest"))
    northwest = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="to_southeast", verbose_name=_("Nord-vest"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Județ")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Județe")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def neighbours(self):
        neighbour_counties = {}
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            if field.related_model == County:
                neighbour_counties[field.name] = field
        return neighbour_counties
    neighbours.fget.short_description = _("Vecinii")
```

In this example I want to add two instances: Olt and Teleorman. If I create Olt and specify Teleorman as its eastern neighbour, how can I automatically set the western neighbour of Teleorman to Olt?

My idea was to get a list with the eight neighbour fields as a property and it works fine until I try to get the field instances in the signal handler. I need to reverse the neighbours list and get the opposite value of that one which was recently changed: if I change the value of county1.east, I need a way how to get the west as the fild which should be updated in the county2.

How should the pre_save signal handler look like? Is the neighbours @property properly written?

Comment: On your first example of `Olt` and `Teleorman`, you can access the west side of `Teleorman` by accessing `.to_west` right? So if you have a FK `east`, which has `related_name='west'` (or in your case `to_west`), you already have east and west in just one field.

Comment: So you can set the relationship by simply using: `olt.east = teleorman`. `olt.east` will be `teleorman` and `teleorman.to_west` or `teleorman.west` will be `olt`

Comment: I understand your point of view and it's pretty logical. However, I'm trying to also add Teleorman.west = Teleorman.to_west. Is there a way to do it? How could I, for example, catch the string "to_west", trim the "to_" part and get "west" as the field name to be updated? 
Maybe my design has no mmuch sense, I don't know, but in the template I'm listing the neighbours, and the "to_..." fields don't appear there. This is the reason of this question.

Comment: I think it's because the relationships are defined as `ForeignKey`. So `to_west` for example will be a manager, so the actual usage is `to_west.first()`. One way to solve this is define all the foreign keys as one to one. Ill try to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I see to solve this is to define only half of the directions and use the reverse related name for the other half. But in order to do this, you need to define the fields as `OneToOneField`:

```py
class County(models.Model):
    north = models.OneToOneField(
        "self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="south"  # the other side
    )
    northeast = models.OneToOneField(
        "self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="southwest"  # the other side
    )
    east = models.OneToOneField(
        "self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="west"  # the other side
    )
    southeast = models.OneToOneField(
        "self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="northwest"  # the other side
    )
```

And then use them like so:

```
c1 = County()
c2 = County()
c3 = County()

c1.north = c2  # this means c2.south == c1
c2.southeast = c3  # this means c3.northeast == c2
```

And so on. This way you don't have to worry about setting the other side of the direction. Also the `OneToOneField` will also make sure that only one county can be the north of another county at a time.

Comment: This is a new approach for me... it's better than the complex thing I was trying to accomplish, but there's a little problem here. What happens if I need to directly specify one of the fields which currently appear as related_name values? For example, c1.south = c3

Comment: You can't. You can only do `c3.north = c1`, but this will be the same as saying `c1.south = c3`

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I found something potentially useful, the model.field.related_query_name attribute, we'll see where will it conduce me. :)